# Avoid Space between String and Sequence while concatenate

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> select 'TMP' || to_char(sq_id.nextval, '000000') res
  2    from dual
  3  /

RES
----------
TMP 000006

SQL> select concat('TMP',to_char(sq_id.nextval, '000000')) res
  2    from dual
  3  /

RES
----------
TMP 000007
```

Please Explain me how to avoid space between the above concatenated String

Answer (score 2):

It is because `to_char(sq_id.nextval, '000000')` produces a **leading space** in the output.

Let's see:

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE sq_id;

Sequence created.

SQL> select to_char(sq_id.nextval, '000000') from dual;

TO_CHAR
-------
 000001
```

You could use **LTRIM** to trim the leading space:

```
SQL> SELECT 'TMP' || ltrim(to_char(sq_id.nextval, '000000'), ' ') res FROM dual;

RES
----------
TMP000002

SQL>
```

Alternatively, you could use the **FILL MODE** format model.

Form documentation:

> FM
>
> "Fill mode". This modifier suppresses blank padding in the return
>   value of the TO_CHAR function

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT 'TMP' || ltrim(to_char(sq_id.nextval, 'FM000000'), ' ') res FROM dual;

RES
----------
TMP000003

SQL>
```

Comment: @user3157300 You're welcome! Please mark it as answered, would help others too.

Answer (score 1):

To Avoid the space that is comming from to char method using FM (that is removing trailing spaces):

```
to_char(sq_id.nextval,'FM000000')
```